# In Gin-Rummy, what is the bonus points for Gin and Undercut?

Tags: scoring, gin-rummy

In the traditional rules of Gin-Rummy:

1. Is going Gin worth 20 or 25 points?
2. Is undercutting worth 10 points?
3. If a player knocks and is undercut by their opponent and this opponent lays off and has no deadwood, do they get a Gin bonus of having no deadwood?

Comment: One variant of rules can be found [here](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/ginrummy.html)

Comment: It looks like you are asking multiple questions and it is best to split them up into separate questions so they can all get properly answered

Answer (score 3):

Gin-Rummy has many scoring variantions.  As Andrew suggested in a comment, Paget is a good source for rules of card games.

From Paget:

> Some people play that the bonus for going gin is 25 (rather than 20)
>   and the bonus for an undercut is 20 (rather than 10). Some play that
>   the bonus for an undercut, the bonus for going gin, and the box bonus
>   for each game won are all 25 points.

The score on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gin_rummy#Scoring) are 25 points per gin, undercut and box bonus.

Both Zinga's popular app [Gin Rummy Plus](https://www.zynga.com/games/gin-rummy-plus/), and [cardgames.io](https://cardgames.io/ginrummy/) use 25 points bonuses for undercuts, gin and box bonus.

For the third question, the answer is no, that player just get the undercut bonus.